# Pass reference to a parent object to function wanting child object

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, parent

I have parent class "Entry", which has two childern, Income and Expense. I would like to be able to have a function which works like this:

```
bool SomeObject::removeEntry(Entry& item, list<Entry> *l)
{
    if (l==&incomeHis)
        return removeIncome(item);
    if (l==&expHis)
        return removeExp(item);
}
```

Is it possible? function `removeExp()` requires object of class `Expense`. Since I am passing it by reference, I know it should be okay, but compiler does not agree.

Comment: Do you actually mean parent and children or are those two derived from the base class? That's a difference.

Comment: You can pass a derived class to a function expecting the base class, but not the other way round.

Comment: You could achieve that by using `dynamic_cast<Income&>` - but it looks very much like a bad design decision. What would you need such a function for? And I hope it's not `std::list<Entry>` because then it would contain neither Incomes nor Expenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is correct in that it can't ensure that every `Entry` on that line happens to be an `Expense`.

You've *designed yourself into a corner*, so to speak.

A better design would be to make `SomeObject::removeEntry` directly perform whatever logic is common to `removeIncome` and `removeExp`.  Where the logic differs, call a **virtual function** on `item`, which can differ between the two types.